# Кодировка при отправке данных на сервер

Tags: android, utf-8, httpclient

Не могу заставить приложение корректно отправить криллицу, получаю знаки вопроса. Кодировку расставил где только нашел возможным. Скрипты на сервере в UTF8, база тоже.

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
HttpProtocolParams.setHttpElementCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
httpParams.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(2000));
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", HTTP.UTF_8);
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(ServerURL);

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

Charset chars = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
builder.setCharset(chars);
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
FileBody fb = new FileBody(file);
builder.addPart("file", fb);

builder.addTextBody("name", name, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN );  //Для теста тип указал в одной переменной           
builder.addTextBody("address", address);

HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
postRequest.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
responseText = getContent(response);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно передать кириллицу из приложения?

Comment: А если не с андроид приложения отправлять, а, допустим, с php скрипта? Можно и с другого сервера.

Comment: Да, проверил, хорошо отправился. Код не могу в комментарии написать, не форматируется. Но добавилось корректно.

Comment: я пока думаю, что у Вас сервер портит кодировку. Больше пока версий нет.

Но в любом случая - если есть возможность - запустите любой tcp снифер и посмотрите, что там именно передается.

Я в подобных случаях часто запускаю netcat и смотрю на вывод. Пример - запустить сервер на 8080 порту

    nc -l 8080

Понятно, что это работает под линуксом. Как под виндой - ищите самостоятельно. Но скорее всего на Вашем сервере линукс, так что получайте доступ по ssh и вперед.

Comment: Пока тестирую локально, под виндой. Но поставил снифер, и, к сожалению, уже с телефона уходит неверно.  http://f3.s.qip.ru/NYzSw0xZ.png  - скрин со снифера

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, кому-нибудь пригодится.
Вот так сработает:

```
builder.addTextBody("name", "value", ContentType.create("text/plain", MIME.UTF8_CHARSET));
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, правильно или нет, по мне так костыль из гнилого тростника, но работает.
При добавлении текста, я его кодирую

```
builder.addTextBody("address",URLEncoder.encode("адрес тут", "UTF-8"));
```

Соответственно на стороне сервера

```
$address = urldecode($address);
```